# Java - Pack referenced libraries into jar file and re-use

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jar

When I create a new Java project that use third party dependencies such as MySQL-Connector, and export this into a jar file to use in another Java project, how do I avoid having to add (again) the MySQL-Connector library to the new projects build path?

What I would like to achieve is to pack down referenced libraries with the jar file, so when I add it to a new project its dependencies are already met within the jar "container" and I can avoid

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

**>>Example<<**

When working with my SQL database I first need the MySQL-connector library, this of course have the prepared-statements methods, update query and so on. But it doesn't have (as far as I know) for example a method for multiple query updates or updates with an unknown number of ?,?,? arguments etc. So for my own part I have created a SQL manager project that contains a class that contains all the SQL methods I need.

I then import the MySQL-connector -> into the manager project and I would like to export this entire project as a self-contained jar file so when I import the manager jar into a project that needs a database, I don't need to both import the manager jar and the connector, but just the manager that than contains the connector.

Comment: Do you use any build system like Maven or Gradle?

Comment: I do not, so far i just export projects through Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what to do technically (in Eclipse, as you tagged it):

1. Open your project`s properties and click on "Java Build Path".
2. Switch to the tab named "Order and Export".
3. Make sure to check the checkboxes for all the jars you want to have in your jar.

But there is one more thing to do: you should carefully check the licence of the jars you want to include in this way because you may not be allowed to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and license suggestion!
I have tried to follow your steps, creating a new file.jar that would also contain the external librari (jar file).

For creating the jar (eclipse)
right click project -> export -> java -> jar file -> unfold the project tree
And here i dont see an option to create the jar with external jars (referenced libraries), i only see this option if i create a runnable jar, which is not what i want.

Is this because that what i am trying to do is "bad practice" or is their a more correct way to add dependencies to your projects?

Comment: How do you want to use you jar? If you just want to use it from other projects in the same workspace, there is no need to export the jar. Just open the project settings (right click properties on the proejct`s main node in Project or Package Explorer) and follow the steps above. In the other projects, add the exporting project as a dependency under build path. Sorry, have to go home now. If it doesn't work, I can help tomorrow.

Comment: I dont know how to explain this with 500 characters and no tools, so i will try and redo the topic, so it becomes more clear what i want to achive.

Comment: I have updated the topic, hope it makes more sense else please let me know. Also i dont know the official "correct" way of getting around with this, so if their is a better or more correct way please let me know.